# Syntax error case postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
select  utilizzo.dataconsegna   case    when utilizzo.dataconsegna<=current_timestamp 
                    then    sum((EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-(EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataritiro)::integer)/36000) 
                    else    sum(((EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-((EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-(EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp)::integer)))-
                        (EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataritiro)::integer))/36000
                    end
from    vettura join prenotazione on prenotazione.targa=vettura.targa 
    join utilizzo on utilizzo.smartcard=prenotazione.smartcard AND utilizzo.dataora=prenotazione.dataora
where   vettura.targa='cn533sr' AND(current_timestamp-prenotazione.dataritiro<=interval '7 days')
```

Hi, i'm having a syntax error on this case, can you help me out? :/

Comment: Can you put the error output? Tthat should show you where could be the problem.

Comment: All the basic information is missing. Postgres version, verbatim error message, purpose of your query. There is not even a column alias for your expression

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the `sum()` *into* the `case`.

You need to sum the *result* of the case:

```
sum(case
     when utilizzo.dataconsegna<=current_timestamp 
       then (EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-(EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataritiro)::integer)/36000 
     else ((EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-((EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataconsegna)::integer)-(EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp)::integer)))-
                    (EXTRACT(epoch FROM utilizzo.dataritiro)::integer)/36000
end)
```